# Inserting row into join table?

Tags: javascript, orm, rdbms, bookshelf.js

I have a `many-to-many` between `Songs` and `People`. The join model isn't specified because it only has three columns: primary key, `song_id` and `person_id`.

Bookshelf definitions:

```
//Song
Bookshelf.model("Song", {
    tableName: "songs",
    people: function() { 
        return this.belongsToMany("Person", "people_songs");
    }
});

//Person
Bookshelf.model("Person", {
    tableName: "people",
    songs: function() { 
        return this.belongsToMany("Song", "people_songs");
    }
});
```

Given a song id and person id, I want to add a row to the join table. [Attach](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/479#issuecomment-54753426) seems to be the correct method to use on the model instance, so in a controller I can do...

```
Models
    .Song
    .forge()
    .where({id: 1})
    .people()
    .attach( new Models.Person({id: 1}) )
    .then(function(instance) {
        res.send();
    });
```

When I query out the rows, `song_id` is null? (I should make the columns `notNullable()` but that's besides the point...)

I also tried [`updatePivot`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-updatePivot) like this:

```
Models
    .Song
    .forge()
    .where({id: 1})
    .people()
    .updatePivot({song_id: 1, person_id: 1})
    .then(function(instance) {
        res.send();
    });
```

But that didn't even insert anything into the join table. However, if I log out the result of the `updatePivot` promise I get this:

```
relatedData: {
    targetTableName: "songs",
    targetIdAttribute: "id",
    joinTableName: "people_songs",
    foreignKey: "song_id"
    otherKey: undefined,
    parentId: undefined,
    parentTableName: "people",
    parentIdAttribute: "id",
    parentFk: undefined
}
```

Comment: I created a test project and got your same (unsuccessful) results. It seems like we're not doing it right. Did you get farther?

Comment: @Esteban Yeah I'm working on it now. I've been reading some of the example projects the bookshelf.js site links to and off the top of my my head this way seems wrong because you have to `.save()` the model instance first, then `.attach()` the association, I could be wrong though. The docs are extensive but the concepts are really abstract.

Comment: Yes, they lack good examples IMO. Also, I tried the `.save()` first and it didn't make a difference :(

Comment: This is the sample I've been studying https://github.com/qawemlilo/nodeza/blob/master/models/post.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution here in a [repo issue](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/133#issuecomment-30920989).

```
//get the model
Models
    .Song
    .forge({id: 12})
    //but I have no idea why save is being used here instead of fetch
    .save()
    .then(function(model) {
        //get the other model you want to add to the join table
        return Models
                .Person
                .forge({id: 56})
                .save()
                .then(function(target) {
                    //need to send both references down the promise chain
                    return {target: target, model: model};
                });

    })
    .then(function(references) {
        return references
                .model
                //get the belongsToMany relation specified in your Model definition, it returns a collection
                .people()
                //attach the target to the collection, not the model instance
                .attach(references.target);
    })
    .then(function(relation) {
        res.send();
    })
```

The result was

```
people_songs

id  |  person_id  | song_id
___________________________

3   |  56         |  12
```